# Retaining HTML Markup when using XML .InnerText

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument, innertext

I have HTML markup being read from an XmlDocument using InnerText as below. However, once read into the string "content";

```
string content = Convert.ToString(XmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/update/content").InnerText);
```

The HTML markup is lost.

How can I retain the HTML markup by the time the node content is in the string "content".

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use InnerXML as below, instead of InnerText.

```
string content = Convert.ToString(XmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/update/content").InnerXml);
```